# How to send data from Arduino IoT to another IoT via Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, broadcast, arduino-nano

I do have two Arduino Nano 33 IoT. I want to make the first IoT to broadcast or send a data to the second Arduino IoT via Bluetooth. Say I want to send the time from the first IoT to the second IoT so they have the same time in sync?

The ArduinoBLE library is complicated to follow. It doesn’t even have a clear example that works. Can anyone help me how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the links below for starting with BLE as a wireless technology and understanding how it is used on Arduino:-

- [Getting Started with Bluetooth Low Energy](http://oreilly.com/library/view/getting-started-with/9781491900550/ch01.html)
- [Arduino BLE Example Explained Step by Step](https://rootsaid.com/arduino-ble-example/)